# How to download image using Selenium WebDriver in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here's the workflow

1. goto a Url using FireFoxDriver  - DONE
2. Save a list of all images on this page - DONE
3. foreach image in this saved list 
   use WebDriver.NavigateTo().GoUrl(imageUrl) - DONE

Question: How to Get / Save The Image Stream into a file on disk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the context, but if you really just want to save the file to disk, you don't to use Selenium for that, you could just use the WebClient.DownloadFile() method.

Comment: Because the session is autenticated and we can't autenticate using WebClient